# Show or hide a div via button and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I need hide a div opening a webpage (display is set on "none"), but clicking on a button the div has to appear.
I'd like to know why the code works until I declare css styles into each div: if I define css in a style block into the head (commented below) and remove style tag from each div, the JavaScript looks almost death.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="it">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Prova visualizzazione div via button</TITLE>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script>
 function apriMenu() {
  var idTag;
  idTag = document.getElementById("appari").style;
  if (idTag.display == "none") {
   idTag.display = "block";
   idTag.top = document.getElementById("header").style.height + "px";
  } else if (idTag.display == "block") {
   idTag.display = "none";
  }
 }
</script>
<!-- <style type="text/css">
 header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #22ffff;
  height: 40px;
 }
 #appari {
  width: 49%;
  background-color: #ff22ff;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
 }
</style> -->
</HEAD>

<body>
<header id="header" style="width: 100%;
  background-color: #22ffff;
  height: 40px;">
 Questo è l'header<br />
 <div id="side">
  <button onClick="javascript:apriMenu();">Clicca</button>
 </div>
</header>
<div id="appari" style="width: 49%;
  background-color: #ff22ff;
  height: auto;
  display: none;">
 Questo è il div appari
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element.style` only gets inline styles, what you are looking for is the computedStyle

So there for you need to use  `window.getComputedStyle()`

See code sample:

```js
function apriMenu() {
  var idTag;
  idTag = document.getElementById("appari");
  var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(idTag).display;

  if (displayStyle === "none") {
    idTag.style.display = "block";
    idTag.top = document.getElementById("header").style.height + "px";
  } else if (displayStyle === "block") {
    idTag.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #22ffff;
  height: 40px;
}

#appari {
  width: 49%;
  background-color: #ff22ff;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  Questo è l'header<br />
  <div id="side">
    <button onClick="javascript:apriMenu();">Clicca</button>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="appari">
  Questo è il div appari
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into it too deeply, you could just add a final else statement to show the element if style.display is empty. Just use the reverse case if you want the element to be shown initially.

```
function apriMenu() {
    var idTag;
    idTag = document.getElementById("appari").style;
    if (idTag.display == "none") {
        idTag.display = "block";
        idTag.top = document.getElementById("header").style.height + "px";
    } else if (idTag.display == "block") {
        idTag.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        idTag.display = "block";
        idTag.top = document.getElementById("header").style.height + "px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simpler way to achieve the same thing: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ZsAKiwxVA3riRx5Y?open=lib%2Fscript.js

```
function toggleMenu() {
   var element = document.getElementById("appari");
   element.classList.toggle("showMenu");
}
```

You basically just need to toggle a class on and off to hide/show the menu. I've found using a class to do so is quite simple.

Good luck!